# How should I host the servers for my project?

Tags: azure, hosting, cloud, distributed-computing

I have started work on a game project which is expected to have a very high load on the servers.
My original plan was going with a general main server which hosts general game data and using a collection of servers hosting a node (or game world) server, being balanced with more CPU/network intensive worlds being hosted in less numbers on the machine.
Now I was wondering how it's best for me to set up the actual servers. Should I go with a cloud like Microsoft Azure, should I host it all myself on own bought hardware or should I use dedicated hosting from some hosting company?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Windows Azure actually has a Toolkit for Social Games which might provide some good guidance.
https://github.com/WindowsAzure-Toolkits/wa-toolkit-games

On Github the architecture section might also help you think about an Azure Solution 
https://github.com/WindowsAzure-Toolkits/wa-toolkit-games/wiki/architecture

Re: Servers, the cloud is a perfect match for this workload/use case, you can grow quickly or fail fast depending on how successful you are and only ever pay for what you use. Azure has a IaaS and PasS offering which should meet all your needs (inc Windows and Linux on IaaS)

Answer (score 0):

Well I believe now days people are engaged in social games; I believe you would be doing the same.

unsure about the development environment I suggest you to look at the [Game Hosting](http://aws.amazon.com/game-hosting/) by amazon.. It could be somewhat costlier but better then to have your own provided it meet all your needs.

You can also check  [gamersisle](http://www.gamersisle.com/) who allows you to rent game server based on your wish so you can rent more when you feel you are hitting client counts.

Happy game development.

P.S :- I always wonder how people build game.. just learning how? ;)

Comment: In response to the P.S: In this case I'm writing the game in C# XNA with the server side software either in C# or in C++ depending on what I'm gonna host it at.

Comment: +1 for XNA.. I was wondering some android game with Microsoft azure.